# Can I upload images to Google Code ?

Tags: google-code

Can I upload images to Google Code?

I was wondering if I can upload all my project resources such as .png files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Just include them as resources in your SVN.

Comment: I'm actually having trouble uploading a jpg and a png. If I just add an image, I receive the following message from the server after 4 5 minutes: "502 Bad Gateway". Do you maybe know why ?

Comment: No idea. My project has a .png and an .ico file. Sounds like a generic error. Are you using SVN, or another SCM?

Comment: I'm using SVN (I've selected it in Google code settings) and I'm using a SVN client for mac called "Versions". I've no idea eiher.